# Subdomain mapping on Go Daddy to HTTPS site on AWS EC2 Instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a subdomain demo.mysite.com which is hosted over godaddy.com. I have successfully mapped the subdomain demo.mysite.com to my AWS elastic IP in the go daddy console

On my AWS EC2 instance my website is secured runing over HTTPS and I have deployed the certificates corresponding to demo.mysite.com on my AWS EC2 instance. Now the problem I am facing is

1 - When I access my subdomain  it points to my EC2 instance and the URL in my web browser changes to my Elastic IP ie www.demo.mysite.com --->> https://201.12.34.58:8443/myApp , which must not happen and it must remain as https://demo.mysite.com

2 - And since my URL changes so I start getting the certificate error saying

The certificate is only valid for demo.mysite.com.
 Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Can someone help in solving these two issues, I feel that if first issues gets solved the second issue will automatically get solved. I am not sure though

Guys I need your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to manage your domain DNS with CloudFlare. Add a CNAME record for your subdomain demo which points to that IP. On CloudFlare Console go to Crypto > Origin Certificates. Create a new one with RSA, then import it to AWS Certificate Manager at **us-east-1**. For the certificate chain use [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-). Be sure that **Always use HTTPS** in Crypto tab is on. After some minutes you should be using your domain pointing to AWS with HTTPS working fine.

That's what I did to make a subdomain to work with an AWS API endpoint with SSL.

Comment: Thanks Steven I need to check if that's feasible for me